# How to control the position of a label to be between the Frame and the plot

Tags: plotting, legending

How can we get this layer arrangement of the output content: curve, label, and frame on top?

I want to send the curve in this code to the back behind the curve and frame.

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -6, 6}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotHighlighting -> None, Axes -> False, 
 Prolog -> {Text[
    Framed[Pane["(a)", {60, 60}, Alignment -> Center], 
     FrameStyle -> Lighter[Gray, 0.8], 
     FrameMargins -> {{1, 0}, {1, 1}}, 
     Background -> Lighter[Gray, 0.8]], Scaled[{0.05, 0.93}]]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Show[Plot[Sin[x], {x, -6, 6}, PlotRange -> {0, 1},
    PlotHighlighting -> None, Axes -> False, Frame -> True], 
 Graphics[
  Text[Framed[Pane["(a)", {60, 60}, Alignment -> Center], 
    FrameStyle -> Lighter[Gray, 0.8], 
    FrameMargins -> {{1, 0}, {1, 1}}, 
    Background -> Lighter[Gray, 0.8]], Scaled[{0.05, 0.93}]]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use `Epilog` instead of `Prolog`

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -6, 6}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotHighlighting -> None, Axes -> False, 
 Epilog -> {Text[
    Framed[Pane["(a)", {60, 60}, Alignment -> Center], 
     FrameStyle -> Lighter[Gray, 0.8], 
     FrameMargins -> {{1, 0}, {1, 1}}, 
     Background -> Lighter[Gray, 0.8]], Scaled[{0.05, 0.93}]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: but in this case the gray rectangle will cover the frame and ticks, as I  mention, I want the frame and ticks to be in front of all

Comment: Maybe `Scaled[{0.1, 0.83}]`? - But in this case we see the top of the plot

Answer (score 1):

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -6, 6}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
 Frame -> True,(*PlotHighlighting\[Rule]None,*)Axes -> False, 
 Epilog -> {Text[
    Style["(a)", 16, Background -> Lighter[Gray, 0.8]], {-5.7, 
     0.94}]}]
```

[image]